# I want to close an application during installshield

Tags: batch-file, installshield, installscript

While the MSI is running I want the application to start then immediately following I want it to stop and close out.
I have a batch file to start the application below:

```
START C:\EmulatorSer\EmualtorSer.exe
```

would the opposite just be

```
END C:\EmulatorSer\EmulatorSer.exe
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out and then come back :P.

Comment: Did you check to see if the executable has any command line arguments you can pass to it to stop it?

Comment: if not, use [taskkill](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html).

Comment: taskill worked way better

Comment: @JFrosty, while it may work way better in your humble opinion, it is not always the best way to shut down an application.  Using `taskkill` could cause data corruption if the program is in the middle of a write process.  Always check the programs help file first if there is an option to gracefully shut down the application programmatically.

Comment: What does the EXE file do once you run it that makes you want to launch it and then exit?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use msi's killprocess custom action after you launch your bat file. In custom action add a "New Kill process", schedule it after you run your bat file. Once you add the killprocess function, add ISTerminateProcesses property in your property manager and set it to your app - you do not need the .exe, set ISTerminateProcesses to EmualtorSer

You can also give this a list, EmualtorSer;app1;app2;etc...